# checking column value if 1 return 1 else 0

Tags: php, sql

I have one function disp where i am passing value of column name of a table to check whether for that column value is 1 or 0   in database. If value is 1 it should return 1 else 0   This is the function i tried to make . But not giving desired result.

please tell me if there is some other way to check value of a column in particular row is 1 or 0

```
 function disp($x){
   @$ncenter=$_SESSION['ncenter'];
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT('$x') FROM sel WHERE 'numcenter' = '$ncenter' and '$x' = 1";
  $sql.=';';
   echo $sql;
 $res = mysql_query($sql);
  if(!$res) die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
  if($row["COUNT('$x')"] > 0){

            return 0;
        }
      else{

            return 1; 
        }
 }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like the logic is the problem - he's switched the 1s and 0s. Though I've never seen "COUNT($x)" being passed before within an array. First time for everything..

Comment: @Duniyadnd : yes may be . But how can i do that in other way ? That is a column name in particular row . any suggestions ??? Thank u

Comment: @deceze : question is i tried making function in that way but its not giving desired result . My requirement is for one column value in a row if value is 1 it should return 1 else 0 . in my example $x is the column name . This is just a try . Thank u

Comment: Can u please rephrase your question and tell us what you want it to do instead of telling us it does not do what you want it to do. Also your code is horrible, it has no error checking whatsoever and it is highly vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
// SELECT * FROM sel WHERE 'numcenter' = '$ncenter' and '$x' = 1 LIMIT 1

if(empty($row)){
    return 0;
}
else{
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: This is a bad use of `empty`. Use `!$row` instead (though that probably won't work either in this case).

Comment: @deceze You're right, I had a face palm moment when I looked at the SQL statement (it would never be empty). Adjusted that. I don't particularly agree with the "bad use" comment unless you have a reason for that that can change my mind.

Comment: My reason: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: Interesting article you wrote, bookmarked and will look at it later - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SQL CASE statement:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN `column_name` = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `column_name_equals_one` FROM `table_name` WHERE `row_identifier_column_name` = 'row_identifier_value';
```

EDIT: i also rewrote your code as it hurts my eyes (i have not tested this).

```
/**
 * Checks if the value of a specific field equals 1 or 0
 * 
 * @param string $columnName The name of the column
 * @param string $rowIdentifier The row identifier
 * @returns boolean|integer Returns false on failure or the query result as an integer on success
 */
function disp($columnName, $rowIdentifier) {
    $returnValue = false;

    $query = sprintf("SELECT (CASE WHEN `%s` = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `result` FROM `table_name` WHERE `row_identifier_column_name` = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($columnName), mysql_real_escape_string($rowIdentifier));

    if (($result = mysql_query($query)) !== false) {
        if (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false) {
            $returnValue = (int)$row['result']
        }

        mysql_free_result($result);
    }

    return $returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$row = mysql_result($res, 0, 0); 
$numb_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($row);
  if($numb_of_rows > 0){ 

            return 1; 
        } 
      else{ 

            return 0;  
        }
```